# Render html inside div and resize its content

Tags: html, render

The system I'm working on will generate invoices and several documents in html format.

When someone searches for this documents, the results must appear with a small preview of the document. The client wants the html documents to be shown inside a div (note that this div is way smaller than the actual document size), what I am trying to achieve is to display the html inside the div and that the content resizes automatically to the div's size.

If I render the html inside the div, it will just add scrollbars and display it in it's original size, I want the html content to fit the div's size.

I've worked in a css sheet that changes fonts, widths, heights for the elements inside the containing div, but as there isn't really a pattern in the html structures for all the documents, the results are not the expected ones, I wonder if there is a cleaner way to do this, maybe with javascript or a jquery plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `scale` on the div, which scales down everything inside it.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/ is the reference for all CSS transformations. Looks a bit like overkill, but there doesn't seem to be a W3C page that explains about scale only.

Anyway, the CSS you can use is something like this:

```
.preview {
    width:600px; height:400px;
    -webkit-transform:scale(.25);
    -ms-transform:scale(.25);
    transform:scale(.25);
    -webkit-transform-origin:0 0; 
    -ms-transform-origin:0 0; 
    transform-origin:0 0; 
    border:4px solid green;
    margin:0 0 -300px 0;
}
```

and the result looks like http://jsfiddle.net/asxqL/4/

Note that although most measurements are multiplied by 0.25 here (for instance, the 4px border comes out as 1 pixel wide), the vertical space taken up by the element is still 400 pixels. That's where the bottom margin of -300px comes in.

Comment: You're welcome. But I was a bit hasty with my answer: the version as posted here only works in Firefox and Opera. If you want it to work in Chrome/Safari and IE as well, you will have to include the `-webkit-` and `-ms-` versions of the transform properties too. See [new jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asxqL/4/). Sorry for that. I updated my answer.